# Retornar data com timezone de Brasília

Tags: php, data

Alguém sabe como eu coloco o fuso horário de Brasilia nesse código?

```
$file_path = "file.zip";
$file_update = date ("Y-d-m G:i:s", filemtime($file_path));
$date = date("n/j", filemtime($file_path));
$hours = date("H", filemtime($file_path));
$sec = date("i", filemtime($file_path));
$h = $hours + 3;
if ($h > 12) {
   $h = $h - 12;
   $t = 'PM';
} else {
   $t = 'AM';
}
$file_date = $date . ' @ ' . $h . ':' . $sec . ' ' . $t . ' ET';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a função [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) para definir o horário utilizado pelas funções de datas.

Adicione esse código na primeira linha do seu arquivo.

```
date_default_timezone_set ('America/Sao_Paulo');
```

Outra forma é definir essa configuração direto no php. Adicione ou modifique essa linha:

```
date.timezone = America/Sao_Paulo
```

[Lista com todas as time zones disponíveis.](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Comment: Muito Obrigado!